# Setup keymap for "Mark Sources Root"?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I work for a large company and am often checking out packages and configuring projects in Intellij. I'm trying to configure keybinds for the following commands:

- Mark Sources Root
- Mark Tests Root
- Mark Resources Root
- Mark Test Resources Root

etc.

In the keymap I only see the following

- Mark Generated Sources
- Unmark Generated Sources
- Unmark Sources Root

Where's all the rest of them? Can I configure shortcuts for those?